# wrong date is given using gmdate

Tags: php, date, time, timestamp, mediawiki

i am making a mediawiki extension , trying to print the Article timestamp

```
$timestamp = $myArticle->getTimestamp();
$time = gmdate("D, d M Y H:i:s",$timestamp);
```

the problem that the timestamp is : 20110807230546

but the given time is : Tue, 19 Jan 2038 03:14:07

why ?

Comment: `20110807230546` is not a Unix timestamp. It seems to be a YYMMDDHHIISS string - you'd have to parse it as such.

Comment: ok thanks a lot ,is there any quick way to parse mediawiki timestamps ?

Comment: See e.g. [Reformat a date in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/q/2863625) you could edit the example in the accepted answer to your needs

Answer (score 0):

```
echo gmdate('D, d M Y H:i:s', strtotime($timestamp));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [`wfTimestamp()`](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual%3aWfTimestamp):

```php
$time = wfTimestamp( TS_RFC2822, $timestamp );
```